# Find natural numbers $n$ so that $n^n+1$ and $(2n)^{2n}+1$ are all primes

Tags: prime-numbers

I have this question: Find natural numbers $n$ so that $n^n+1$ and $(2n)^{2n}+1$ are all primes.
My idea is that we consider:

- $n=1 \Rightarrow n^n+1=2$ and $(2n)^{2n}+1=5$ (correct)
- $n=2 \Rightarrow n^n+1=5$ and $(2n)^{2n}+1=257$ (correct)

And then, we prove that, with all natural numbers $n$ is greater than $2$, we don't get any primes like above. I mean the solution of problem is $n=1$ or $n=2$. But i don't know to prove that.

Comment: Note:  if $n$ has an odd factor, say $n=2^km$ where $m>1$ is odd, then $x^n+1=\left(x^{2^k}+1\right)\left(x^{n-2^k}-x^{n-2^{k-1}}+\cdots+1\right)$

Comment: Do you mean: "Find _all_ natural numbers $n$..."? If so, this is an open problem $-$ see lulu's answer.

Comment: Oh yes. I mean all natural numbers n

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to prove it for odd $n$ ($n > 1$). In this case, $n^{n}+1$ is even, so it can't be prime.

Comment: I don't understand where x is from

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ has a non-trivial odd factor, say $n=2^km$ where $m>1$ is odd, then $$x^n+1=\left(x^{2^k}+1\right)\left(x^{n-2^k}-x^{n-2^{k-1}}+\cdots+1\right)$$

This, for example, $x^{96}+1=\left(x^{32}+1\right)\left(x^{64}-x^{32}+1\right)$

It follows that, in this case, neither of your terms are prime.

That only leaves the case in which $n$ is a power of $2$.  Your expressions would be examples of [Fermat primes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatPrime.html) and little is known about these in general.  Indeed, the largest known prime of the form $2^k+1$ is $2^{16}+1=65537$ and it is possible that there are none larger.  Certainly none have been found despite extensive searching.  Still, though, nothing general has been established.

Comment: What about when $n$ is odd?

Comment: @Airdish  If $n$ is odd then it is not a power of $2$.

Comment: Oh my mistake the $x^n + 1$ argument will obviously work when $n$ is odd :P